# Bring an Activity to the front using Android TaskManager

Tags: android, taskmanager

I am running into an issue with bring up an `Activity` to the front.

1. When the app is launched the user sets some time  (Activity 1)
2. Now the app shows a count down time with time decreasing (Activity 2)
3. Now I press the home button.
4. Choose Task Manager, select my app shown in the list and select "Switch To" to bring the app to the front, instead of Activity 2 it ends up on the Activity Screen 1.

What can I do so the task manager switches to the most recent `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not using FLAG_NEW_TASK when launching Activity 2.